# Yocto: Add custom user to custom group

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have created a custom group e.g "grp1" in my application recipe say "app.bb".

```
GROUPADD_PARAM_${PN} = "grp1"
```

I am trying to add my custom user e.g: "user1" to this group "grp1" in "space.bb".

```
USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-d ${localstatedir}/lib/space/ -s /bin/false -G grp1 -U user1"
```

The useradd command failed: "**useradd: group 'grp1' does not exist**". 
I have also tried adding `DEPENDS_${PN} = "app"` in space.bb, but it doesn't help.

How can I add my custom user to my custom group in bitbake recipe?

Comment: Syntax is wrong for DEPENDS variable, it should be `DEPENDS = "app"`

Comment: @Nayfe DEPENDS_${PN} doesn't not work for this problem? or syntax is wrong in bitbake recipe?

Comment: For bitbake recipe, it is `RDEPENDS_${PN} = "app"` or `DEPENDS = "app"`, but in our case it's `DEPENDS` you need i think, you can check the following [topic](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2017-October/038377.html). Which Yocto version do you use?

Comment: @Nayfe Am using rocko. I will check the topic and DEPENDS, Thanks

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: @yeger: I think I haven't solved the problem. But I can suggest you to try having the `group`, `passwd` files in a directory called `files` inside your meta layer. I hope yocto automatically copies this to `recipes-sysroot` and use it when processing it. So you can create group in `group` file and use it in `USERADD_PARAM`

Comment: Have you ever found a proper solution?

Comment: @Étienne Not yet. I haven't checked this for a while. If you have success with latest Yocto versions, please post it.

Comment: I have not really found a proper solution. What I did is that I created the user and group directly on the target using "pkg_postinst_ontarget()", but this may not be doable in other use-cases for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**
If you can redefine all the needed groups inside your recipe as they didn't exist before, it works just fine.

---

They way I'm working with that is:

Even inside your `space.bb` I redefined the groups from `app.bb`, like:

```
inherit useradd
...
# Forcing group from app.bb to exist here
GROUPADD_PARAM:${PN} = "grp1"

USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-d ${localstatedir}/lib/space/ -s /bin/false -G grp1 -U user1"
```

It causes some duplication but at the end inside the distro itself everything works as fine and there's no duplication of groups at all.

Answer (score 0):

another possible cause of this error, if some recipe is using

```
inherit extrauser
```

instead of

```
inherit useradd
```

and adding the same group **grp1** with the help of

```
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
      useradd -p '' grp1; \
      groupadd grp1; \
      "
```

instead of classical

```
GROUPADD_PARAM_libAPP = "grp1"
USERADD_PARAM_libAPP = "--no-create-home --home /var/tmp --shell /bin/nologin --gid grp1 grp1"
```

will cause a group **grp1** duplication and failure of the **useradd** command

Answer (score 0):

Paiusco's answer works by fixing symptoms of a missing dependency.

To make it cleaner, find out which recipe creates the group (e.g. search all *.bb files for the group name). As `useradd` needs the group to exist, your recipe *depends* on the other recipe to run first.

Thus, add to your recipe:

```
DEPENDS += "recipe-that-creates-the-group"
```

This should fix it in a proper way. For more info, read the section on [DEPENDS](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#term-DEPENDS) in the reference manual.